GAS assembler. Can I write my own macro tag?
I'd like to make @object_t macro type of this syntax. Will be used to create an object of key-value pairs.
use:
.section .data
  obj: @object_t (
    name: .string "Tom",
    age: .int 22
       )

.section .text
.global main

main:
  # code
  pushq $obj.name
  # code

Are there any ways to solve the hard implementation? With macros, we can only write instruction logic, pseudo-instructions. But the tag-macro is probably a different case.
How to create a GNU GAS macro that expands to an expression like "(x+y*240)*2"?
